# Union-Find Disjoint+ Path Compression Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, union-find

I'm having an exam this sunday and I just want to confirm if what I'm doing is correct ( You know exams make me skeptical)

This is how the algorithm works:

```
￼int Find(int x)
{ // Return the set containing x and compress the path from x to root
  // First, find the root
int z = x; while (P[z] > 0) { z = P[z]; } int root = z;
// Start at x again and reset the parent // of every node on the path from x to root z = x;
while (P[z] > 0)
{ int t = P[z];
     P[z] = root; // Reset Parent of z to root
z = t; }
return root; }
```

This is the question:

> Recall the algorithms developed for the Union-Find problem on disjoint
>   sets from a set of n elements. Find uses path compression and Union
>   uses ranking. Also, Union of two trees of the same rank chooses the
>   root associated with 2nd argument as the new root.  Start with a set S
>   = {1, 2, ..., 10} and 10 disjoint subsets, each containing a single element. a. Draw the final set of trees after executing:
>               Union(1,2), Union(3,4), Union(5,6), Union(1,5), Union(1,3).

And this is my solution to the question:

[image]

I would love to have any tips or suggestions regarding this Algorithm.

Thanks!

Comment: Your third step is wrong.  1 should point to 6 instead of 2.  Also, each root should have a rank.

Comment: Unrelatedly, there are better things to do with your youth than memorising algorithms and running them on paper.  The analysis of union-by-rank with path compression is, by comparison, a much better thing to be doing.

Comment: You mean the 4th step? where I union(1,5)? but the find(1) with path compression happens on the set {1,2}.

Comment: @tmyklebu Actually, path compression is useless(slower) after some tests compared to regular union-find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point of Find operation of `Union-Find Set` is ***path compression***.

If we know the root of set A is `r1`, and the root of set B is `r2`, when join set A and set B together. The most simple way is to make set B's root as set A's root, which means `father[r2] = r1;`

But it is not so "clever", when `r2`'s son, we say `x`, wants to know its root, `x` asks its father `r2`, and then the father `r2` asks itself's father `r1`, blabla, until to the root `r1`. Next time when asked `x`'s root again, `x` asks its father `r1` "*what's our root?*", there is not necessary for `r1` to repeat the previous loop again. Since `r1` already knows its root is `r2`, `r1` can directly return it to `x`.

In brief, ***`x`'s root is also `x`'s father's root***. So we get how to implement ***path compression***(I think recursion is more straightforward):

```
int Find(int x)
{
    // initial each element's root as itself, which means father[x] = x;
    // if an element finds its father is itself, means root is found
    if(x == father[x])
        return father[x];
    int temp = father[x];
    // root of x's father is same with root of x's father's root
    father[x] = Find(temp);
    return father[x];
}
```

It is extremely high performance, about time complexity of path-compressioned find operation, see: http://www.gabrielnivasch.org/fun/inverse-ackermann